# ¿Cómo validar achivos de audio (mp3, wav, etc) en Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, archivo, audio

Tengo un formulario donde tengo un input "File" para subir un archivo, la cosa es que quiero subir SOLO archivos de audios, no quiero subir imágenes ni mas nada, solo audio. Como lo tengo actualmente sube cualquier archivo a una ruta que especifiqué en ***config/filesystems.php***

Aquí les dejo mi formulario:

```
<div class="form-control-file">
  <label for="file">Subir Cuña:</label>&nbsp; <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Se recomienda subir solo archivos de audio menores a 2 MB!"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a>
    <input type="file" name="file">
       @if($errors->has('file'))
         <span style="color:red">{{$errors->first('archivo')}}</span>
       @endif
</div>
```

Mi controlador para guardar es el siguiente:

```
public function saveaudio($file){
    $name_file=time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
    if(\Storage::disk('audios')->put($name_file, \File::get($file))){
        return $name_file;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $event = new Event();
    $event->campaign_id=$request->campaign;
    $event->cunia_id=$request->cunia;
    $event->version_id=$request->version;
    $event->fecha_programada=$request->fecha_programada;
    $event->fecha_fin=$request->fecha_fin;
    $event->hora_programada=$request->fecha_programada;
    $event->medio_id=$request->tipomedio;
    $event->circuito_id=$request->circuit;

    if (!empty($request->file)) {
         $name_file=$this->saveaudio($request->file);
         if ($name_file!=false){
            $event->address=$name_file;
        }
    }

    if($event->save())
    {
        //Una forma de crear variables de session
        return back()->with(['msj'=>'Se realizó la operación con exito']);
        return redirect()->route('listspautas');
        // return redirect()->action('PautasController@index');
    }else{
            return back()->with(['nomsj'=>'No se realizo la operación']);
            return redirect()->route('listspautas');
        }
}
```

La pregunta es: **¿Cómo validar para que solo se pueda subir archivos de audio?**

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La validación podrías hacerlo desde el frontend con Javascript, te dejo un ejemplo:

En tu JS :

```
function validarExtensionArchivo(){
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
    var filePath = fileInput.value;
    var allowedExtensions = /(\.wav|\.mp3|\.mp4|\.mid)$/i;
    if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)){
        alert('Solo se permite archivos de audio con esta extensión .wav/.mp3/.mp4/.mid .');
        fileInput.value = '';
        return false;
    }else{
        //Otro Código
    }
}
```

En tu HTML :

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="return validarExtensionArchivo()" />
```

Te comparto un [Enlace de Referencia](https://www.codexworld.com/file-type-extension-validation-javascript/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, intentaré comparto si me funcionó.

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad la validación del lado del servidor no debería de faltar, está bien validar del lado del cliente (y ciertamente no lanzando un simple `alert()` ya que no hay nada de UX lanzando esas alertas) pero la validación del lado del servidor no debería de faltar, ¿qué tal si me meto al inspector de código y le cambio el id a tu input?

La validación del lado del servidor sería algo así:

```
//Hasta arriba de la clase importa Validator
use Validator;


$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'file' => 'required|file|mimes:mp3,mp4,wav,mid',

            ]);
if($validator->fails()){
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
            }
```

Si tu input es opcional solamente agregas antes un: `if($request->hasFile('file')){}` para que valide sólo cuando exista en tu request.

También puedes crear un Request corriendo el comando `php artisan make:request` pero tu input tendría que ser required todo el tiempo, checa la documentación oficial para más información:

Para validación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation
Para requests: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation

Agrego también que es una mala práctica poner inline events en las etiquetas HTML ya que el código pierde legibilidad y para mantenerlo te va a costar más trabajo estar buscando en etiquetas HTML.

Comment: Wow! Muchas gracias, probaré de esa forma para ver.